# Running a query by using hive -f which is returning a syntax error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
hive -f ${path}/hive_load_$tablename.hql -hivevar ${db}=$db -hivevar ${START_DATE}=$START_DATE  -hivevar ${end_date}=$END_DATE
```

This the is code i am trying to run. Path,db,start_date,end_date are the parameters which will be passed from another file. This is the error i am getting.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.1.0-129/0/hive-log4j.properties
NoViableAltException(16@[202:1: tableName : (db= identifier DOT tab= identifier -> ^( TOK_TABNAME $db $tab) |tab= identifier -> ^( TOK_TABNAME $tab) );]).
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: error suggest that there is a syntex error. Can you check if all the variable are set properly and query in the file has no error.

Answer (score 0):

The variables aren't being passed in correctly. It should be

```
hive -f ${path}/hive_load_$tablename.hql --hivevar db=${db} --hivevar START_DATE=${START_DATE} --hivevar end_date=${END_DATE}
```